# Hydrogen Sulfide New Superconductor? Is It Possible For Hydrogen Sulfide?

Tags: electricity, superconductivity

According to a very trusted science source : https://www.zmescience.com/science/news-science/superconductivity-artic-temperatures-05342/

There is now such thing as a Hydrogen Sulfide Superconductor at the low temperature of -25.6 degrees Fahrenheit.

How is this possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Even if your source is correct, you don't want to use hydrogen sulfide as a superconductor.  This stuff is also a super-killer of humans.  In the gaseous form, one whiff of 100% hydrogen sulfide is guaranteed to kill you within minutes!

Comment: At extremely high pressures (see the actual papers in Nature and Science), it appears to be possible. Unless you live deep in the Jupiter cloud layers this doesn't seem to be particularly practical on Earth. And, David White is being fairly melodramatic, although H2S is a well-known killer in confined spaces.

Comment: Is it killer or not, having superconductivity on such a high temperature is  very promising.